# Android Amazon AWS Cognito Workflow confirmation

Tags: android, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've been having some issues understanding the Amazon AWS Cognito Workflow for adding multiple login providers, here is some psedu code to demonstrate my questions:

```
{Code to get CognitoCachingProvider}

Device Cognito ID = A

{Code to get Google Token}

withLogin(Google Token)

if(Identity is changed)
 identityListener(
Device Cognito ID = ID in Cognito Pool)
else(
Device Cognito ID = a;
cognitoprovider.setLogin (Google Token);
)

withLogin(Facebook Token);
if(identity is changed)(
*****Device Cognito ID = ID in cognito Pool;*****
cognitoprovider.setLogin(Google TOken);
cognitoprovider.refresh();)
else
(Cognitoprovider.setLogin(Facebook Token);
cognitoprovider.refresh();)
```

So my real question is in the second step.  Let's say that I want to bind both Facebook and Google to a specific Cognito ID.

Three examples:

1)  There is no Cognito ID assigned - assign Google+ and Facebook 
2)  There is a cognito ID assigned with Google and no Facebook
       - The acquisition of the Google Login should not affect the Cognito ID
       - The acquisition of the Facebook Login is simply added as another provider
3)   There is no cognito ID assigned with Google but one with facebook:
      - The acquisition of the Google Login creates a new and separate cognito ID that is immediately overwritten by the Facebook Login Token's associated Cognito ID

Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your understanding of the first two scenarios is correct. To throw more light on this, Amazon Cognito has two concepts when dealing with multiple providers: Linking and Merging. Linking is when on a single device you are logged in with provider A and already have an identityId and you login with provider B. In this scenario the identityId will remain the same and provider B will be **linked** to the existing identity. Now let us say that you are logged in with provider A on device X and with provider B on device Y. Both these end users(identities) will have their unique identityIds. Now if you login with provider A on device Y, it will result in **merge** of these two identities and return you an identityId which will have both providers associated with it. I hope this clears any confusion around using multiple providers.

Thanks,

Rachit